# How to divide content of ArrayList<String, int> into two different columns

Tags: javafx, arraylist, gridpane

I have this ArrayList that you see underneath. I wish to divide my ArrayList into three columns, one showing the "category" of the item e.g. pizza or burger, one showing the names e.g. margherita, and one showing prices. Furthermore I wish to have a row for every item, so 12 rows. I have tried to enter the content of my ArrayList into a GridPane, but I simply cant get that to work.

```
public abstract class MenuItem {

private String name;
private double price;

public MenuItem(String name, double price) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

    public void setName(String name) {
}

public String getName() {
        return name;
}

    public void setPrice(double price) {
}

public double getPrice() {
        return price;
}



public class OrderMenu {

private ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems;


public OrderMenu(){

            menuItems.add(new Pizza("Margherita", 50));
            menuItems.add(new Pizza("Hawaii", 55));
            menuItems.add(new Pizza("Marinara", 70));
            menuItems.add(new Pizza("Meat Lovers", 70));
            menuItems.add(new Pizza("Calzone", 60));

            menuItems.add(new Burger("Burger", 60));
            menuItems.add(new Burger("Cheeseburger", 65));
            menuItems.add(new Burger("Baconburger", 60));

            menuItems.add(new Soda("Coca cola", 25));
            menuItems.add(new Soda("Coca cola light", 25));             
            menuItems.add(new Soda("Fanta", 25));
            menuItems.add(new Soda("Faxe kondi", 25));  

}
```

Comment: TableView fits better for purpose you described.

Comment: Ive already made it into a tableview im just not too happy about the looks, so I was hoping for another option :)

Comment: The looks and the control are not coupled. `TableView` is the most logical control. If you want to customize it you can do it easily. Look at the JavaDocs or other questions on this site. If you can't find a way to do what you want, ask a question about customizing the looks of the `TableView`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really clear... but i guess you want to put that ArrayList info, into some table/columns.

You can use ObservableList to check all the changes in your data:

```
private ObservableList<MenuItem> menuItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

You can set some TableView and TableColumns in your controller like this:

```
@FXML
private TableView<MenuItem> menuTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<MenuItem, String> nameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<MenuItem, String> priceColumn;
```

Then, in the same controller, set the columns when you initialize the controller:

```
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
          cellData.getValue().getName());
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
          cellData.getValue().getPrice());
    }
```

And then, from your main class, when you set the mainApp to this controller you can set all the items in your list to this table:

```
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
        menuTable.setItems(menuItems);
    }
```

Hope this can help you, here you have a full example of this:

https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part2/